# Taking Input through a string in c++

Tags: c++, c, string, input

In C, suppose I need to take input from a string

```
 int num,cost;
 char *name[10];
 printf("Enter your  inputs [quantity item_of_name at cost]");
 scanf("%d%*c%s%*c%*s%*c%d",&num,name[0],&cost);

 printf("quantity of item: %d",num);
 printf("the cost of item is: %d",cost);
 printf("the name of item is: %d",name[0]);
```

**INPUT**

1 book at 12

**OUTPUT**

Quantity of item is: 1

The cost of item is: 12

The name of item is: book

Now I want to do the same thing in C++. And I have no idea how to approach. gets() returns the whole string.Is there any specific function that I am missing out on? Please help.

Comment: Your question is a bit confused because your C code doesn't take input from a string but from standard input. What are you really trying to do? Also the C functions you are using will also work in C++.

Comment: His C code is broken anyway: he passes an uninitialized pointer as the third argument to `scanf`.  And even if it were initialized: users can easily crash the program with a long enough name.  In C, you _never_ use `"%s"` in a `scanf` without specifying the maximum length.

Comment: All I am trying is making use of format specifiers to store the appropriate input (in the string )into corresponding variables. Now I have never seen usage of C functions (or what we use in C) in C++. (I am not saying you can't..just I am still a beginner).Basically I am trying to transpose the problem from C to C++.

Comment: @Peps The C++ way of doing input is given by sehe, but the C way works too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int num,cost;
std::string name;
std::cout << "Enter your  inputs [quantity item_of_name at cost]: ";
if (std::cin >> num >> name >> cost)
{ } else 
{ /* error */ }
```

You will want to add errorhandling

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you should rather use `cin`, `cout` and `string` from standard library.

Answer (score 0):

You could use iostream's cin.

```
int num,cost;
 char *name[10];
 std::cout <<"Enter your quantity"<<std::endl;
 std::cin>> num;
 std::cout<<" Enter the cost"<<std::endl;
 std::cin>>cost;
 std::cout<<"Enter the name"<<std::endl;

 std::cout<<"The quantity of the item is: "<<num<<" costing: "<<cost<<" for "<<name[0]<<std::endl;
```

and then of course you could also use std::string instead of char*.

Or streamline the cin's as cin >> num >> cost >> name;

Also, as **Griwes** noted, you will want to perform error checking on your results.

Comment: Yeah, but I would imagine that goes without saying.

Comment: OP looks like newbie (generally, he looks like someone educated that C++ is just "C with classes" and taught some C basics), so I think it's important remark here.

Comment: My assumption is that because he was using (well knew how to) a array of char pointers, that he knew error handling, but in my sedation didn't stop to consider this could be a homework question and that code just have been provided. Good catch, and noted as well.

Comment: Your code yields the same undefined behavior as the questioner's. Better replace `could` with `should` and tell him/her about the error.

Answer (score 0):

In c++, [std::stream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/) provides the read and write communication with the user through the `>>` operator.

Your code translates to

```
int num,cost;
std::string name;

std::cout << "Enter your  inputs [quantity item_of_name at cost]" << std::flush;
std::cin >> num >> name;
std::cin >> at; // skip the at word
std::cin >> cost;

std::cout << "quantity of item: " << num << std::endl;
std::cout << "the cost of item is: " << cost << std::endl;
std::cout << "the name of item is: " << name << std::endl;
```